# Why is the intersection of CFL and RL not always RL?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

Suppose M is a CFL and N is aa RL. Then wouldn't the language generated by the intersection of M and N contain strings, some of which are accepted by both DFA and PDA? So if they are accepted by a DFA as well, then why is the generated language not an RL?

Comment: "contain strings, some of which are accepted by both DFA and PDA" -- not "some", *exactly* those!

Answer (score 5):

Let $C=\{0^n1^n\mid n\ge 0\}$, a known CFL. Let $R=\{w\in\{0,1\}^*\}$, a known regular language. Then $C\cap R = C$, which is not regular.

Answer (score 3):

Being *a* set of strings accepted by some DFA is not the same as being *the* set of strings accepted by a DFA.

It is true that, if $M$ is context-free and $N$ is regular, then $M\cap N$ is a set of strings, all of which are accepted by some DFA – the automaton that accepts $N$ must accept all strings in $M\cap N$. However, to say that $M\cap N$ is regular is something stronger: $M\cap N$ is only regular if it is *the* set of strings accepted by some DFA, i.e., if there is a DFA that accepts every string in $M\cap N$ and rejects every string not in $M\cap N$.  The automaton that accepts $N$ accepts every string in $M\cap N$ but also accepts every string in $N\setminus M$. Therefore, unless $N\subseteq M$, the automaton that accepts $N$ also accepts a bunch of strings that aren't in $N$.  So, just knowing that $N$ is regular (so there's an automaton for it) isn't enough to show that $M\cap N$ is regular.